Selecting one item from X-Macro list in C
I have a x-macro like this:
#define X_LIST \
   X(1, "name 1") \
   X(2, "name 2") \
   ...
   X(n, "name n")

I need create another macro to allow me select the second argument from one specific X from the x-macro.
I expect, I have some macro like
#define SELECT_X_TEXT(nr)
//somewhere where should be used X_LIST maybe with some arguments 

and when I use:
SELECT_X_TEXT(2) //should expand to "name 2"

I've found the tips and tricks with macros in C link but not fully understood that. I guess, I could use some combination of  'IF' 'WHEN' 'EQUAL' macros to solve my issue

C and C++ are different language, please keep the tag only for the language you actually use. And as a side note in C++ you should use macros very rarely (if at all).

What is the underlying and actual problem you try to solve this way? Right now your question is an XY problem. Please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Then [edit] your question to improve it.

X_LIST does not take arguments and you can't define a macro from a macro. There is no context. It can be done in a few define undef macros, not with a macro.

As a possible hint, you can define and undefine macros; And you don't have to use all arguments to a macro. You could have something like #define X(a, b) b and not use a at all. You can use it to create multiple "lists". But, again, it really depends on the actual problem you try to solve. There might be other ways.

As it happens, there were a couple of good late answers to the linked duplicate very recently. Check out the answers by Heath Raftery as well as yours sincerely, could you use either of those tricks? (If you think that nothing in that post works, then please poke me and I'll re-open the question.)

Although in this very case the cleanest and most obvious solution in this specific case is simply to create a look-up table array (through X-macros) of type const char* const where the number is the index.

Yet another possibility since 2 is a compile time constant would be to write a macro like a chained ?: where you keep checking (1 == 2) ? (2 == 2 ? ..... Although code like that would be dirt ugly and bad if executed at run-time, the compiler will boil it down to just a single expression during optimization - the one where 2 == 2 is true.

Firstly refactor you code to pass context to the macro, which will simplify maintanance and context.
#define X_LIST(X) \
   X(1, "name 1") \
   X(2, "name 2") \
   X(n, "name n")

Then you can write a macro that will expand for example only the 2nd element:
#define X_PICK2_1(...)
#define X_PICK2_2(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define X_PICK2_3(...)
#define X_PICK2_4(...)
/* etc. */
#define X_PICK2_n(...)
#define X_PICK2(n, ...)  X_PICK2##_##n(__VA_ARGS__)

After that you can:
#define X_LIST(X) \
   X(1, "name 1") \
   X(2, "name 2") \
   X(n, "name n")

#define X_PICK2_1(...)
#define X_PICK2_2(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define X_PICK2_3(...)
#define X_PICK2_4(...)
/* etc. */
#define X_PICK2_n(...)
#define X_PICK2(n, ...)  X_PICK2##_##n(__VA_ARGS__)

const char *str = X_LIST(X_PICK2);


I expect, I have some macro like

Is impossible with your current X_LIST that does not take an argument and depends on global state. You would have to first:
 #define X X_PICK2

And then you would have to #undef X before using it again.
